# how do I get WPA2 connection to work using wl.ko proprietary driver?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, broadcom, wicd

for some time I've been using local WPE wi-fi, which was simply managed using iwconfig, using the following line of commands on the startup:

```
sudo modprobe wl && sudo ifconfig eth1 up && sudo iwconfig eth1 essid <my_network_name> && sudo dhclient eth1
```

however, things have changed and now I need to use WPA-2 type of connection

to achieve that, I've [downloaded](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wicd) and installed Wicd network manager, which starts to detect connections after I execute the following:

```
sudo modprobe wl && sudo ifconfig eth1 up
```

the problem is, despite it works fine connecting to WPE, it completely fails to get along with WPA-2: when I enter 'properties' for my WPA-2 connection, I can't save any keys I enter, nor 'cancel' or 'ok' buttons seem to work anyhow

at last, I've tried to read manuals and configure /etc/network/interfaces, having the following:

```
iface eth1 inet dhcp
wpa-driver wext
wpa-ssid <my_wifi_name>
wpa-ap scan 1
wpa-proto RSN
wpa-group CCMP
wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
wpa-psk <my_pass_HEX>
auto eth1
```

I've commented what I had there before:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

sadly, when my system loads it takes several minutes at the boot configuring the network, which ends with no success

so, since nicely working Wicd manager would be the best option, I'd gladly use any possible method to get online again.

I'm running Linux Mint 14 Nadia kernel 3.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the loopback entries *must* be included. I suggest this /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <my_wifi_name>
wpa-psk <my_pass_HEX>
```

Now get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup -v eth1
```

The '-v' is for verbose; some additional information will be available to show what's happening as it tries to connect.

Does it now connect on boot?

Comment: I've altered the 'interfaces' file as you've offered, and now it does connect after I insert wl.ko and run ifup -v eth1

however, it doesn't establish a connect during the boot due to timeout

Comment: When you boot and do nothing else, is wl loaded? lsmod | grep wl We can fix that easily.

Comment: no, it's not, I load it using a script at /usr/bin which executes the following 'sudo modprobe wl'

Comment: Not the ideal way to do it. Add to /etc/modules the simple wl. Please see my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get wl to load at boot time, add it to /etc/modules:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

loop
lp
rtc
wl
```

Also check /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf to be sure it isn't blacklisted, preventing it from loading on boot as expected.

Comment: everything work on boot now, thanks. 

so in case I need to use another WPA2 I'd need to alter the info in /etc/network/interfaces accordingly and bring eth1 down and up again?

Comment: Yes, or if it's more convenient, go back to Wicd or Network Manager. Each method has its advantages and disadvantages.