# Wifi stopped working after boot on Ubuntu 18.04 with Lenovo laptop

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, lenovo, broadcom

On my Lenovo Edge-15 running `18.04.5` with kernel `4.15.0-122-generic`. Secure Boot was disabled all along.
**I just noticed one day on boot that the Wi-Fi wasn't working. When I went to the Wi-Fi settings I got "No Wi-Fi adapter found". Could an automatic update have turned something off/broken something?**

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d1100000-d1107fff
```

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4360] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4360]
```

and

```
$ iwconfig
vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.
```

Is Wi-Fi blocked?

```
$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Continuing working through [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395).

```
$ sudo apt list bcmwl-kernel-source
Listing... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source/bionic-updates,now 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Purging that per the instructions. Restarted and still no Wi-Fi.

```
$ sudo update-pciids
Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2020-10-11 03:15:01
```

Per the table, for `14e4:4360` I need to install

```
$ sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Rebooting and still no Wi-Fi.

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43    
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

After a comment from chili555

```
$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-122-generic
```

A quick search of the output suggests this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/811015/334823

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,544 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.15.0.122.109 [2,544 B]
Fetched 2,544 B in 0s (28.8 kB/s)                 
(Reading database ... 442641 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.122.109_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.122.109) over (4.15.0.122.109) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.122.109) ...
$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-122-generic
```

I ran `$ sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and it got rid of the error from `sudo modprobe wl` (which now returns nothing). But still no Wi-Fi.

```bsh
dmesg | grep wl
[   52.474364] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   52.474369] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   52.478450] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   52.481565] wl driver 6.30.223.271 (r587334) failed with code 1
[   52.481568] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_detach : 
[   52.481569] NULL ndev->ieee80211ptr, unable to deref wl1
```

After searching that 2nd line of output I found https://askubuntu.com/a/261934/334823, which I tried, but no change so reverted.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` Did you read and follow this part of the link you gave? "In some computers, before performing the commands, you will need to deactivate the Secure Boot Options in your BIOS."

Comment: Edited. I'm about to try disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: I believe you need: `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: That got rid of the other message, but no Wi-Fi. Finally got into the BIOS only to discover that Secure Boot was disabled all along.

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl`?

Comment: Added result, tried searching the error message a bit, but didn't find anything to try that seemed to have worked

Comment: I suggest that you add to the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1879547 I can, so far, find no solution.